# Does a Nepali need a transit visa for Panama or Colombia?

Tags: transit-visas, colombia, panama, nepali-citizens

I am a Nepali passport holder, right now in the Dominican Republic. I have a DR visa. Recently I thought of visiting Bolivia as a tourist. I can't find any direct flights to Bolivia. Do I need a visa to transit in either Panama or Colombia?

Comment: Welcome to the site. My edit was to make your question a bit more understandable; apologies if I have misunderstood. Am I correct that you are asking whether you need a visa to transit, or how to get one while in the DR, or both?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't pass immigration in Panama you don't need a visa:

> International travellers in transit in Panama do not require a visa provided they don't pass immigration and are staying less than nine hours.

(Source: [VisaGuide](https://www.worldtravelguide.net/guides/north-america/panama/passport-visa/))

A Colombia visa is not required:

> A visa is not required for direct airside transit through Colombia. Traveler must be in possession of a valid passport and onward ticket, and must remain in the airport's transit area. Proof of Travel Arrangements: Confirmed round-trip or onward airline ticket.

([Non-governmental source](https://colombia.travisa.com/VisaInstructions.aspx?CitizenshipID=US&CountryID=CO&TravelerTypeID=TR&ResidenceID=US&PartnerID=TA))